# Problems when switching from Development to Production Enviroment Blazor WASM hosted on Azure App Service

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor hosted web application and host it on Azure web services. So far so good, everything is fine when I run it with the Azure configuration setting Enviroment Varibale ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development. But when I change it to Production, I get an HTTP ERROR 500. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please share the details of the error ?

Comment: That's part of my problem, I can't see any more information except that it doesn't work. No exceptions, no messages , nothing. Just HTTP ERROR 500 in Browser. How can I get more information?

Comment: In F12 is there any error message under console tab?

Comment: "the server responded with a status of 500 ()". What changes when i switch to "Production"? What i have to prepare in the source?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the steps followed by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65665086/15997690)

Check again your APP whether it is running or not otherwise follow below step

The 500 errors are application loading error/ Internal server error. You can Enable [Local Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-local-cache-overview)  by adding the following key under `“Application Settings”` in the ***Azure Portal***.

```
WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION = Always
```

Refer [here for steps](https://community.akumina.com/knowledge-base/addressing-500-server-error-on-web-app/)

Or

Diagnostic the 500 error please have look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the missing SSL certificate.